Is this hose bib fixable from the outside?
I have a hose bib that is leaking from the spout. I removed the handle in an effort to replace the washer on the stem, but the inside did not look like I was expecting. I have two questions:

Is this leaking hose bib repairable from the outside of the house, or will I have to cut into a wall on the inside of the house?

If the hose bib is not repairable from the outside, is it replaceable from the outside, or will I have to cut into a wall on the inside of the house?






Try just putting the handle on, and turning out.  It might pull the insides out.

The warning on the plastic cover plate: "REMOVE HOSE OR FAUCET MAY FREEZE OR BURST" suggests that this hose bib may very well be an antifreeze type with the valve seat back inside the house at the end of a pipe. In this case the valve stem is part of a rod that extend down inside the pipe to the valve seat.

Having removed the packing nut, now remove the valve stem from the faucet. Terminology-wise, it's a frost-free sillcock, not a hose bib.

It is a Woodford outdoor faucet. They sell the kits to repair it, and it can be done in-place, without removing the whole valve body. Just search online for "Woodford outdoor faucet repair kit" and you will see several suppliers selling them. An example. Make sure to get the right one for your model number.
Then here's a YouTube video showing how to do the replacement from the outside.
Cheers.

Also, if you haven't already, make sure you turn off the water supply first, or you will get very wet very quickly when you remove the stem!

So the interesting thing from the video is that the soft gland packing is already exposed, while OP's photos made it look like that was part of the bronze body casting. Nice, I'm not sure I've seen one of those in the Old World.

@JimmyFix-it - good advice and expect water anyway for a few seconds.

It is worth mentioning that the problem described by OP has naught to do with the packing; he/she could probably just change the bibb washer and reinstall without all the packing work shown in the linked video. Making sure to snug up the packing nut when finished, of course...
